# Is there a "move" command in R (equivalent of <- followed by rm)?

Tags: r

This is one of those "there has to be a function for this" questions.  It's not that big a deal, but it's just annoying enough that every time I rename an object I wonder if there's a better way.

Suppose I capitalize an object that I've created and realize I'd rather have it uncapitalized:

```
# Create test data
X <- runif(100)
# Rename the object
x <- X
rm(X)
```

Is there a one-command way of doing this (that also avoids the re-copy for memory/speed reasons)?  There are a few commands named `rename` in various packages but they all work on elements within a list, rather than on the list (or other object) itself.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but [it has come up](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-March/156035.html) on the R-help mailing list.

Comment: Rumor has it a function like this may be in the `taRifx` package soon. ;-)

Comment: @GSee Ha.  You've discovered my MO.  Solve problems that bug me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a built in way to do this but you could easily write your own function to do something along these lines.  For instance this does just that without any checking to make sure the object exists or whether or not there is already an object named what you want to rename to.

```
mv <- function(x, y){
    x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    y_name <- deparse(substitute(y))

    assign(y_name, x, pos = 1)
    rm(list = x_name, pos = 1)
    invisible()
}
```

Some example use

```
> x <- 3
> x
[1] 3
> y
Error: object 'y' not found
> mv(x, y)
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
> y
[1] 3
```

---

Edit: For those that didn't follow the link in the comments here is a version written by Rolf Turner that does some checking to make sure the object we want to move actually exists and asks us if we want to overwrite an existing object if the new name already has an object in it.

```
mv <- function (a, b) {
    anm <- deparse(substitute(a))
    bnm <- deparse(substitute(b))
    if (!exists(anm,where=1,inherits=FALSE))
        stop(paste(anm, "does not exist.\n"))
    if (exists(bnm,where=1,inherits=FALSE)) {
        ans <- readline(paste("Overwrite ", bnm, "? (y/n) ", sep = ""))
        if (ans != "y")
            return(invisible())
    }
    assign(bnm, a, pos = 1)
    rm(list = anm, pos = 1)
    invisible()
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty similar solution to that found in @mrdwab's link.  Still not as good as just renaming without copying, but good enough for most uses.

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice that link before.  You're right - they are similar but the version in that link I would say it quite a bit better than my version since that one does some checking for you to make sure things will actually work out and you don't overwrite something on accident.  I don't know of a good way to do renaming without copying though sadly.

Comment: @Dason Reading further into the thread above Hadley Wickham says R doesn't copy an object until one of them is modified, so mv function is actually just renaming.

Comment: @lselzer Ah.  I knew that, but for some reason thought it didn't apply here.  Clearly it does.  Cool.